# How can I embed a raw html string into a Text.XmlHtml node structure

Tags: html, haskell, pandoc, heist

This is kind of a corner case.  I'm running Haskell, Text.XmlHtml (version 0.2.3).  I'm getting my source data from Pandoc (version 1.12).  My source files are all in Markdown format.

The corner deals with when I have raw Html directly in my Markdown file.  This is, of course, supported by the Markdown format, and sometimes is the only way for me to get the kind of Table layout that I want.  Pandoc reads the file just file, but then when it gets to the Html section, what it emits is roughly like this:

```
[ RawInline (Format "html") "<a href=\"abcdefg\">"
, RawInline (Format "html") "<img src=\"image.png\" />"
, RawInline (Format "html") "</a>" ]
```

So... converting this into a hierarchical tree could get very complicated.  The desired result, in XmlHtml would be something like this:

```
Element "a" [("href", "abcdefg")] [Element "img" [("src", "image.png")]]
```

But that is very difficult to get when I'm dealing with a structure that was hierarchical (everything else Pandoc emits is nicely hierarchical) and suddenly is not, but that "not hierarchical" part is only findable by basically building an Html parser.  That works on multiple strings that surround other structures.

*ideally*, I would like to emit is a simple TextNode:

```
TextNode "<a href=\"abcdefg\"><img src=\"image.png\" /></a>"
```

I could do that either by emitting a bunch of TextNodes, one for each RawInline, or by glomming together the RawInline elements.  The point is that I want to emit a TextNode that has raw Html in it and have that ultimately rendered without any extra Html escaping.

My renderer is ultimately a Heist snippet, but that probably means it runs by way of Blaze.

My final alternative, which *might* work, is to go from Pandoc through the Blaze Html renderer and then through the XmlHtml parser to get something that I can embed into a Heist snippet.  I'd just like to avoid that because it feels dirty.

(I think I would actually run into the same problem if I wanted to put Java script into my Markdown documents... which is technically allowed by the language but probably very evil.)

Is there a way to do this, or am I too limited by my tools?

*Update*

I tried the route of rendering from Pandoc to Blaze to XmlHtml.  Turns out that I get the same result, with the Html put into the final nodes in escaped from and thus appearing in the browser.  Here was my function (which was much shorter and easier than the full implementation I'd done...)

```
pandocToHtml :: Pandoc.Pandoc -> [XmlHtml.Node]
pandocToHtml = Text.Blaze.Renderer.XmlHtml.renderHtmlNodes . Pandoc.writeHtml Pandoc.def
```

Pandoc.def includes all of the "allow_raw_*" extensions, including allow_raw_html.

Final thing I can think to do is to apply my own piecemeal html parser (and then maybe contribute it to Pandoc).  Which, in the end, couldn't be horribly hard.

Comment: Does `Text.XmlHtml` not have its own parser?

Comment: It does, but it requires that the entire html snippet in a string be well formed. That becomes impossible if I have Markdown I interspersed in the Html simply because Pandoc intersperses the results. What I may resort to us rendering from Pandoc to Blaze and then using an XmlHtml method that renders from Blaze to XmlHtml. I was just trying to bypass that step (or, really, salvage code I put a lot of effort into before discovering the Blaze to XmlHtml path).

Comment: Actually, I just ran a test and discovered that going from Pandoc to Blaze doesn't actually get me the embedded Html correctly, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to do this are to either construct the nodes yourself like this:

```
Element "a" [("href", "abcdefg")] [Element "img" [("src", "image.png")]]
```

...or run your markup through the parser.  This is by design.  The contents of `TextNode` will always be escaped.  XmlHmtl is not designed for pandoc style markdown.  It is designed for XML and HTML.  So you have to get your documents into that format first.  It seems to me like you should be able to use pandoc to render the markdown to HTML and then run the XmlHtml parser on that.

XmlHtml does have a mechanism for interpreting certain portions of a document as raw text (as required by the HTML spec).  You can see which tags are interpreted as raw text [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlhtml-0.2.3/docs/src/Text-XmlHtml-HTML-Meta.html#rawTextTags).  In 0.2.2 we updated XmlHtml to give the user [more control over what gets treated as raw text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlhtml-0.2.3/docs/Text-XmlHtml-HTML-Meta.html#v%3aisRawText).  If you want a node to be treated as raw, just add the `xmlhtmlRaw` attribute to the tag.  If you want a node that gets treated as raw by default to not be treated as raw, then add the `xmlhtmlNotRaw` attribute.

I'm not sure why `renderHtmlNodes . writeHtml def` didn't work for you.  It seems like that should work.  If it didn't work, I think Pandoc's `writeHtml` may be buggy.  Since that didn't work, you might try `parseHtml . writeHtmlString` (pseudocode).

Comment: `parseHtml . writeHtmlString` works.  There's a few other support functions involved, but that works.  So does, however, turning a Pandoc `RawInline (Format "html") "<a href=blah>"` into `Element ("span") [("xmlhtmlRaw", "")] "<a href=blah>"`  I'm not sure which is the better path to use.  Either way, this does point to an error in Pandoc.writeHtml, because it doesn't handle the raw nodes correctly where writeHtmlString does.

Comment: I'm interested in more information about why `renderHtmlNodes . writeHtml def` doesn't work.  It could be a problem with either XmlHtml's blaze renderer or with Pandoc's blaze generator.  I think Pandoc is more likely to blame, but I could be wrong.